# Find an appropriate trigonometric substitution of the form $x=f(t)$ to simplify the integral $ \int x\sqrt{7x^2+42x+59}\,\mathrm dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Find an appropriate trigonometric substitution of the form $x=f(t)$ to simplify the integral $$ \int x\sqrt{7x^2+42x+59}\,\mathrm dx .$$

There were never any examples quite like this in class, so I'm clueless as to how to figure out which trig function to use.

Comment: Inside the square root we have $7(x+3)^2-4$.  Let $\sqrt{7}(x+3)=2\sec \theta$.

Comment: Use [Euler substitutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution). Trigonometric substitutions are a pedagogical abomination.

Comment: If you do want to use a trigonometric substitution (violence against nature aside...) to handle an integral involving an expression $\sqrt{a x^2 + b x + c}$, you can determine which trigonometric function is appropriate using only the sign of $a$ and the sign of the discriminant $b^2 - 4 a c$ of the quadratic.

Answer (score 2):

Try completing the square to get

\begin{equation*}
\int x\sqrt{(\sqrt{7}x+3\sqrt{7})^2-4)}\,\mathrm dx
\end{equation*}

& use the substitution $u=\sqrt{7}x+3\sqrt{7},~du=\sqrt{7}dx.$

Comment: $du=\sqrt{7}dx$.  Please include that last factor.

Answer (score 0):

First, simplify the integral with $x+3=\frac2{\sqrt7}y$

$$I=\int x\sqrt{7x^2+42x+59}\ dx=\frac8{21}(y^2-1)^{3/2}-\frac{12}{\sqrt7}\int \sqrt{y^2-1}\ dy
$$
Then, apply the trig-substitution
$y=\sec t$, $t\in(0,\frac\pi2)\cup(\pi,\frac{3\pi}2)$, to integrate
$$\int \sqrt{y^2-1}\ dy=\int \tan^2t\sec t\ dt= \frac12\tan t \sec t-\frac12\tanh^{-1}\sin t
$$

As a result of back-substitution
$$I= \left(\frac{x^2}3+\frac x2-\frac{71}{42}\right)\sqrt{7x^2+42x+59}+\frac{6}{\sqrt7}\tanh^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{7x^2+42x+59}}{\sqrt7(x+3)}
$$